# Regex extract text inside '**' characters

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex to extract a word from among a plethora of **** characters. I know this is trivial for regex gurus... I'm just having some difficulty with it.

```
 phrase = re.search('\*.*(\w.*)\*', message.text).group(1)
```

Comment: This worked  phrase = re.search('\**(\w+)\*', message.text).group(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For text between arbitrary numbers of *'s, use:

```
phrase = re.search(r'\*+(\w+)\*', message.text).group(1)
```

Note that the `r` to the left of the string like `r'string'` means that the string is completely literal, and no extra escaping is needed beyond normal regex escaping.

If you only want to match on matching sets of starts (`**this**` but not `***this**` or `*this**`) then use:

```
phrase = re.search(r'(?<!\*)(\*+)(\w+)\1(?!\*)', message.text).group(2)
```

To explain:

- `(?<!\*)` is a negative look-behind saying that the regex can't start right after a star, since then that star wouldn't be included.
- `\1` matches the *same number of stars as the first group*.
- `(?!\*)` is a negative look-ahead saying that there can't be any more stars right after the last star in the `\1` group.
- The lookaround groups are zero-length non-matching groups, meaning they don't get counted in `re.search(...).group()`'s group counting.

To do all that for every instance in a string, use something like:

```
phrases = [r[1] for r in re.findall(r'(?<!\*)(\*+)(\w+)\1(?!\*)', message.text)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Close. I think you need to escape the backslashes and remove some `.`

```
phrase = re.search('\\**(\\w+)\\*', message.text).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about: `\*+(\w+)\*+`

Looks for one or more * and then one or more word characters and then one or more *

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/hG7fE2).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> example_string = '** **hello_123** ****'
>>> phrase = re.search('\*+(\w+)\*+', message.text).group(1)
>>> phrase
'hello_123'
```

This also works fine for when there is no whitespace between the asterisks.